# ReactJS, update State with handler but data is empty

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I have this situation:

I want to update some state (an array) which is used to map different React components.

Those componentes, have their own `handleUpdate`.

But when I call to `handleUpdate` the state that I need to use is empty. I think is because each handler method was mounted before the state was filled with data, but then, how could I ensure or use the data in the handler? In other words, the handler needs to update the state that fill it's own state:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [deliver, setDeliver] = useState({items: []});

const handleUpdate = (value, position) => {
  // This set works
  setDeliver({
    items: newItems
  });
  // This doesn't work because "data" is an empty array - CRASH
  setData(data[position] = value);
};

useEffect(() => {
  const dataWithComponent = originalData.map((item, i) => ({
    ...item,
    entregado: <SelectorComponent
      value={deliver?.items[i].delivered}
      key={i}
      onUpdate={(value) => handleUpdate(value, i)}
    />
    }));
    setData(dataWithComponent); // This is set after <SelectComponent is created...
  }
}, [originalData]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The value that you pass don't come from `originalData`, so the onUpdated don't know what it's `value`

You run on originalData using map, so you need to pass item.somthing the the onUpdate function

```
const dataWithComponent = originalData.map((item, i) => ({
    ...item,
    entregado: <SelectorComponent
      value={deliver?.items[i].delivered} // you can't use items use deliver.length > 0 ? [i].delivered : ""
      key={i}
      onUpdate={() => handleUpdate("here you pass item", i)}
    />
    }));
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure, but I think you can do something like that. I hope you get some idea to work it.

```js
// This doesn't work because "data" is an empty array - CRASH
  let tempData = [...data].
  tempData[position] = value;
  setData(tempData);
```

Comment: I tried that too, but `data` always comes empty